# Blender viewport messed up

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I entered a camera view, but after exiting (via the view rotator), the viewport looked messed up. Here are some pictures of what happened. (The checkered box pattern was already there before as a plane, but it has become distorted)
[image]
[image]
How do I fix it? (I don't have num pad on my keyboard)

Comment: you have toggled *[View ‣ Perspective/Orthographic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html)*. If you have no numpad for the shortcut *Numpad_5* you can use the menu of the viewport (or assign another shortcut in the preferences) - or just click the little grid icon below the "view rotator" (the [Navigation Gizmo](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/introduction.html#navigation-gizmo))